# SQL Server 2019: Rasing errors between 1 and 13000

Tags: errors, sql-server-2019, error-log, raiserror

I've been struggling with a task which requires me to raise a number of errors for testing purposes. Of course the time consuming errors are between 1 and 13000. I've managed to do them, but I need to do it several times on multiple test instances and I wanted to ask if there's a way to raise SQL Engine errors which normally only could be raised by the engine itself. By 'a way', I mean any possible routes to generate those error messages.

The ultimate goal is that the messages appear in the current error log.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try `RAISERROR` syntax below;

```
RAISERROR(
          'Test error' -- Error message
          ,0 -- Severity
          ,1 -- State
         ) WITH LOG;
```

For more information, you can check out the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).